# "cannot use as type string in assignment"

Tags: go

I have the following string:

```
-1,856,32,0,0,0.000000,0.000000
0,0,0,137,0,0,0,140
0,0,101,0,0,0,42,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,554,0
-1,841,1,0,0,0.000000,0.000000
0,0,0,163,0,0,0,182
0,0,120,0,0,0,43,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,517,0
```

then I split it by using separator `-1` which mean there will be an array consisting of 2 elements (let's call it `array1`). now, let say on the first element of `array1` I want to split it again by `\r\n`, which will be an array (`array2`) consisting of 5 elements. next, I want to split the first element of `array2` by using `,` as the separator, but it give me a warning saying:

```
cannot use strings.Split(d0, ",") (type []string) as type string in assignment
```

here is the code:

```
array1 := strings.Split(string(b), "-1,")
for k, chunk := range chunks{
    // skip the first
    // because it's blank
    // duno why
    if k == 0{
        continue
    }

    array2 := strings.Split(chunk, "\r\n")

    d0 := data[0]
    d0 = strings.Split(d0, ",") // this give me error: cannot use strings.Split(d0, ",") (type []string) as type string in assignment
    lat, lng := d0[4], d0[5]
    // 
    //  TODO: match lat and lng againts lamp table in DB which is now in $coords
    //  
    fmt.Println(lat, lng)

    data = data[1:]
    for _, v := range data{
        _ = v
    }
}
```

Comment: `d0` has type `string`, the result of spliting it has type `[]string`. You cannot assign a slice to a string.

Comment: Yes that's what i expecting, but it seems `d0` is a `[]string` therefore it give me an error.

Comment: No, you're getting the error because `d0` is a `string`, not a `[]string`. If it were a `[]string` you would get a different error for trying to pass it to `Split`. The return type of `Split` is different from its argument type, therefore you cannot pass `d0` to Split and also assign the result to it.

Comment: ah I got it what you mean, so Go cannot reassign to a different type. in this case I have to assign the result to a new variable called `d1`, and the error is gone. thank you very much @mkopriva.

Comment: Correct, in Go if a variable has a specific type you cannot assign a value of a different type to it.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question is in the error message you noted:

> cannot use strings.Split(d0, ",") (type []string) as type string in assignment

The reason is that you declare `d0` as having type "string" and then you try to assign a *slice* of strings to it. Since those are different types the compiler generates the error you listed and refuses to compile your program.

```
d0 := data[0] // Here we declare d0 as a string and assign a value to it
d0 = strings.Split(d0, ",") // ERROR: "Split" returns a []string but d0 is a string!
```

To work around you should simply declare a new variable that is a slice of strings instead of trying to reuse the name `d0`:

```
d0 := data[0] // Define d0 as a string
ss := strings.Split(d0, ",") // OK: Define ss as a []string
```